# Set HTML hide attribute with js

Tags: javascript

I want to set a hide HTML attribute with JS but it is reseting itself after 1ms. Does anyone know how to set the hide attribute and remove it.

```
<body>
    <form method="post" id="form">
        <input type="text" name="text" id="text" ><br>
        <button onclick="hide()">True</button>
        <button onclick="show()">false</button>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hide() {
        document.getElementById('form').hidden = true;
    }
    function show(){
        document.getElementById('form').hidden = false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Don't rely on `onclick`. Think about users who don't use a mouse. _There are many_

Comment: onclick is also fired when something is touched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `hide()` when you click a **submit** button inside a form.

1. The JavaScript runs
2. The element is hidden
3. The form submits
4. A new document is loaded and rendered (and it isn't hidden in the new document).

Don't use a submit button unless you actually want to submit the form.

```
<button type="button" ...>
```

If you *do* want to submit the form then you'll need to set the `hidden` attribute in the new page. You could do that with server-side code that reads the form data (and you'll need to set a name and value for the `hide` submit button so the data can be picked up by that page).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `display:block`:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

```js
    function hide() {
        document.getElementById('form').style.display = "none";
    }
    function show(){
        document.getElementById('form').style.display = "block";
    }
```